# Is there a way in ASP.NET MVC to make the controller actions authorized as Administrator by default without using the AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make all the actions in the controllers have Adminstrator authorization by default and I will use the AuthorizeAttribute decoration if an action should have another user role other than Administrator. What is the authorization value by default and where is it defined? Can we change the default value?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a property called `AllowMultiple` that allow you to assign multiple `AuthorizeAttribute`s

[See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Attach the attribute to the controller, then you can attach more specific ones to just actions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the end. In order to make all the controllers Adminstrator authenticated by default we need add a global filter with Administrator role in GlobalFilters.asax.cs. This creates a strict global Admin access for all controllers.

Then if we want any method of a controller to have non admin access (with a different role other than anonymous), we need to override the authorization and add the specific role.

`[OverrideAuthorization]
 [Authorize(Roles = NonAdminRoleName)]`

The important thing is the NonAdminRoleName here should include Administrator with the other allowed role names because as we override the authorize attribute it will lose the Admin control on the method.

So it should be a comma separated string like `"Administrator, Member"`